# Switching between jms providers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-jms

I would like to do a SPRING (3.2.1) setup where I can switch the underlying JMS provider depending on the environment you are in e.g. dev, test, prod. I am no expert but have come across @Profile annotation of Spring. I don't really know how to use it. So what I need to do is in DEV environment I want to use ActiveMQ and in PRODUCTION I want to use IBM MQ. Is this possible? If so, would appreciate it if you could provide some config or code to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#new-in-3.1-bean-definition-profiles

For XML config, see this blog... http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

See this blog about @Profile: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/ for using profiles with @Configuration.

It boils down to this...

When using XML configuration, simply add `<beans/>` elements at the end of your spring config files...

```
<beans ...>
    <bean... />

    <beans profile="DEV">
        <bean ... // my ActiveMQ config .../>
    </beans?

    <beans profile="default">
        <bean ... // my IBM (or JNDI) config .../>
    <beans/>
</beans>
```

Then run in dev with `-Dspring-profiles-active=DEV`.

Similarly @Profile can be added to @Configuration classes to limit their use to particular active profiles.

Comment: Thanks for the query reply. I will try this out and post back. Thanks again.